# How should the [open-source] tag be used?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

This site has an [open-source](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/open-source) tag, but I'm struggling to understand how this tag should be used; it has no tag excerpt or wiki, but that's not a problem unique to this tag.

As every question on this site should be about open source one way or another, it could go on every question - but if it's on every question, it doesn't add any information.

Is there a good subset of questions we should use the tag on? If not, it feels to me like we should just delete the tag.

Comment: Comparing the oldest and last active visible questions, looks like this tag was created quite recently on [this question](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/10043/282) (Jun '20)

Comment: Philip, the tag has finally been burninated, and blocklisted.  Sorry about the delay, which was nearly all mine; do you fancy accepting an answer?

Comment: Done (and no need to apologise, this certainly wasn't the biggest issue)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This looks like a meta-tag, at best. And as you mentioned, virtually every question on this site should about open source anyway, so it would be pointless.

Burninate it!

Comment: This is actually an [intrinsic tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/218532/241919) and might even need to be blacklisted.

Comment: @AndrewT.  was not aware of that term, thanks for sharing! And I agree - blacklisting is probably the right way to go - we shouldn't have this tag, and we shouldn't allow it to be created by mistake.

Comment: Side note - we really need a better term than "blacklist". If the Linux kernel moved past it, so can we.

Comment: Sorry, was commenting in a hurry, I should have called it [blocklist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/355815/241919) instead.

Comment: Indeed, this should be blocked as an intrinsic tag. It looks like `[opensource]` is already blocked... which I guess doesn't block `[open-source]`, if the block was added before this issue came up. (EDIT: Looks like the tag still exists. Since the tag's on 50+ questions right now, it's easier for staff to remove it ourselves as part of the tag block process.)

Comment: I just wanted to give an update that we have blocked use of the tag and cleaned up the questions with the tag as well.

Comment: @SpencerG thank you so much!